# A easy question of assignment function of class

Tags: c++, class, assign

I write a class

```
struct opera{
  int a,b;
  int op;
  opera(int a1=0,int b1=0,int op1=-1):a(a1),b(b1),op(op1){}
  opera& operator=(opera& tmp){
    a=tmp.a;
    b=tmp.b;
    op=tmp.op;
}
```

And I want to assign it to an array element like this:

```
ans[a][b]= opera(t.a,t.b,i);
```

Why it can't compile  successfully.

However this can work:

```
opera tmp=opera(t.a,t.b,i);
ans[a][b]= tmp;
```

Of course,the struct opera don't need a explicit assignment function, and

```
ans[a][b]= opera(t.a,t.b,i);
```

can work directly.

Comment: What are the compile errors you're getting?

Comment: the Bo Persson's answer is right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to assign from a temporary, you need

```
  opera& operator=(opera const& tmp){
```

The other line

```
opera tmp=opera(t.a,t.b,i);
```

is an initialization of a new object, and not an assignment.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `opera& operator=(const opera& tmp)` ?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: `const opera &` and `opera const&` is exactly same! Just the syntax is different.

Comment: @Quantum - Yes, but they are identical. You can have the `const` either after the type it is applied to, or before the leftmost one. I chose to make it `const&` for it to stand out as a const-reference.

Comment: Why a temporary must be const?

Comment: @liu - That is just a rule of the language. If the parameter is a temporary and you change its value, the changes will be lost when the function returns. Early users of C++ found this to be a problem, and decided to require const parameters for temporaries so that the compiler could tell them.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic The `const` modifies what precedes it, except when nothing precedes it.  In most contexts (e.g. `int *const`, to make the pointer const, or `void Class::func() const`, to make the function const), you have to put it after what it modifies.  Many people prefer putting it after in every case, for reasons of consistency, and to avoid confusion when typedefs are involved: `typedef int* PI; const PI pi;` gives `pi` the type `int *const`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ans[a][b]= opera(t.a,t.b,i);
```

> Why it can't compile successfully.

That invokes assignment operator that is why it cannot compile because the temporary object created out of `opera(t.a,t.b,i)` cannot be bound to the non-const reference in the assignment operator's parameter. All you need to do is this:

```
 opera& operator=(const opera & tmp)
                //^^^^ note this
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your copy ctor/assignment operator is not taking its parameter by const reference. Otherwise when you use `ans[i][j]=opera(a,b,c);` a temporary object is created, and according to C++ standard, you can not take a non-const reference for this object. Hence you need to use `opera(const opera& o);`